# Add animation to border bottom on input

Tags: html, css

I want the color of the border-bottom of my input to change with an animation when clicked. Similar to the yellow line one this. I want this to be on all the input boxes and the select.

```css
.input_container{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.awsome_input{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
}
.awsome_input_border{
  display:inline-block;
  width:0px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #FEC938;
  position: relative;
  top:-5px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: all ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: all ease-in-out .15s;
}
.awsome_input:hover,
.awsome_input:active, 
.awsome_input:focus{
  outline: none;
}
.awsome_input:hover+.awsome_input_border,
.awsome_input:active+.awsome_input_border, 
.awsome_input:focus+.awsome_input_border{
  width:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="input_container">
<input type="text" class="awsome_input" 
placeholder="What do you think?"/>
<span class="awsome_input_border"/>
</div>
```

I've tried to recreate this in my code but I cant seem to get it right. Any idea how to do this? 
I understand that the span is what creates the yellow line on the snippet but can I recreate this instead to change the border-color instead of adding another line.

My code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="signup-form">
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="line-animation">
        <span class="awsome_input_border" />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="line-animation">
        <span class="awsome_input_border" />
        <select name="country">
          <option value="sweden">Sweden</option>
          <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="us">United States</option>
          <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        </select>
        <span class="awsome_input_border" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>

.signup-form {
  background-color: #efefef;
  width: 50%;
}

.signup-form form {
  padding: 20px 10px
}

.signup-form input[type=text], select {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid darkgrey;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.signup-form input[type=text]:focus, select:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #02add7;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the clue was in the code you provided at the beginning, you need to set what happens to the sibling element on focus:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="signup-form">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="firstname" class="line-animation" placeholder="firstname">
      <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="lastname" class="line-animation" placeholder="lastname"><div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <select name="country">
        <option value="sweden">Sweden</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="us">United States</option>
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        </select><div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.signup-form {
  background-color: #efefef;
  width: 50%;
}

.signup-form form {
  padding: 20px 10px
}

.signup-form input[type=text], select {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid darkgrey;
  background-color: inherit;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: none;
}

.signup-form input[type=text]:focus, select:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.form-group {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-group .line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .3s width ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  top: -14px;
}

.signup-form input[type=text]:focus+.line, select:focus+.line {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #02add7;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6xjyw21m/

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple example. I am not using any `span` and only using **border css**

```css
input { 
  border: none;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
}

input:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
}


select { 
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}
select:hover { 
  border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
}

select:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>INPUT</h3>
<input type="text" placeholder="What do you think?" />


<h3>SELECT</h3>
<select name="country">
        <option value="sweden">Sweden</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="us">United States</option>
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below sample

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.custom-form {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 40px auto 40px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.custom-form .btn-primary {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  border-color: #8e44ad;
}
.custom-form .form-group {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.custom-form .form-group .animated-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: text;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.custom-form .form-group .animated-label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45%;
  height: 2px;
  width: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
.custom-form .form-group.not-empty .animated-label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.custom-form .form-group .form-control {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px 0 5px;
}
.custom-form .form-group .form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.custom-form .form-group .form-control:focus ~ .animated-label {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #8e44ad;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.custom-form .form-group .form-control:focus ~ .animated-label:after {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <form action="#" class="custom-form">
      <h3 class="text-center">Animated Form</h3>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'not-empty': userName.length}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user"  id="user" ng-model="userName"/>
        <label for="user" class="animated-label">Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'not-empty': passWord.length}">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass"  id="pass" ng-model="passWord"/>
        <label for="pass" class="animated-label">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="submit">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled>Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why `Please check` ? better explain what you have done especially when the code is too much ...

Comment: Given the transition effect to .custom-form .form-group .animated-label:after {}

Comment: background-color: #8e44ad;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;

Comment: it's not for me :) i speak in general ... you need to explain what you did IN the answer