# Difficulty decreasing border-bottom and implementing animation transition

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a nav element and when I hover over it, a blue border transitions under. While I'm able to implement the transition effectively with just the :hover pseudo element, when I add the ::after (which is necessary to decrease the distance between the border-bottom and the text), the animation will not work. I've seen threads like this ([Add animation to border bottom on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299680/add-animation-to-border-bottom-on-input)) that accomplish, but it requires multiple divs and spans.

How can I both decrease the distance of the border-bottom from the text and implement the animation transition? Currently, what I have is below, but the animation will not work with the :after selector, and separating it out into just the :hover selector does not work.

```
  .flex-nav li:hover::after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;    
    left:0;
    bottom: 10px; 
    background: none;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    text-shadow: none 0 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1f6fa4; 
    transition: border-bottom .5s ease-out;
}

.nav-item {
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    padding: 0px;
    /* height: 40px; */
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-left: 18px;
}

import React, { Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import './navbar.css';

const Navbar = props => {
  return (
      <Fragment>
        <header> 
            <div className="logo-image">
                <img className="logo-img" src={require("../images/logo.jpg")} alt="Mountain View" />
            </div>
            <nav className="flex-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><NavLink className="nav-item" to="/questions/new">SERVICES</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink className="nav-item" to="/questions">COMPANY</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink className="nav-item" to="/questions/new">STUFF</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink className="nav-item" to="/questions/new">THINGS</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink className="nav-item" to="/questions/new">ITEMS</NavLink></li>
                </ul>              
            </nav>
        </header>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML? And if you can, make a snippet. Thanks

Comment: it's in React so i'm having trouble making a snippet :/

Comment: define the after intially without the hover then change its state on hover .. actually you are createing the element on hove which can create issue with the transition

Comment: when i do that it impacts the position of the nav element, either pushing it up or down

Comment: i think i found a fix messing with the line height. odd it couldn't be done in the nav li selector though.